# Template Parse Error in Angular 2 and Visual Studio update 3

Tags: angular

I am following [ASP.NET Core and Angular 2](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/aspnet-core-and-angular-2) from Packt Publishing. In Chapter 3 the Author Creates an ItemListComponent and ItemDetailComponent. When I use ItemDetailComponent i am getting template parse errors. Below is the error

```
Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'item' since it isn't a known property of 'item-detail'.
1. If 'item-detail' is an Angular component and it has 'item' input, then  verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'item-detail' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message.
("
        </li>
    </ul>
    <item-detail *ngIf="selectedItem" [ERROR ->][item]="selectedItem"></item-detail>
```

below is the Code i have written :

ItemDetailComponent:

```
import {Component, Input} from "@angular/core";
import {Item} from "./item";
@Component({
selector: "item-detail",
template: `
<div *ngIf="item" class="item-details">
<h2>{{item.Title}} - Detail View</h2>
<ul>
<li>
<label>Title:</label>
<input [(ngModel)]="item.Title" placeholder="Insert the
title..."/>
</li>
<li>
<label>Description:</label>
<textarea [(ngModel)]="item.Description"
placeholder="Insert a suitable description..."></textarea>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
`,
styles: [`
.item-details {
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px 10px;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: #dddddd;
width: 300px;
}
.item-details * {
vertical-align: middle;
}
.item-details ul li {
padding: 5px 0;
}
`]
})
export class ItemDetailComponent {
@Input("item") item: Item;
}
```

ItemListComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Item } from './item';
import { ItemService } from './item.service';
@Component({
selector: `item-list`,
template: `
    <h2>{{title}}:</h2>
    <ul class="items">
        <li *ngFor="let item of items" [class.selected]="item === selectedItem" (click)="onSelect(item)">
            <span>{{item.Title}}</span>            
        </li>
    </ul>
    <item-detail *ngIf="selectedItem" [item]="selectedItem"></item-detail>

`,
styles: [`
    ul.items li {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    ul.items li.selected {
        background-color: #cccccc;
    }
`]
})
export class ItemListComponent implements OnInit
{
@Input() class_name: string;
title: string;
selectedItem: Item;
items: Item[];
errorMessage: string;

constructor(private itemService: ItemService) {

}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ItemListComponent instantiated with the following type: " + this.class_name);
    var s = null;
    switch (this.class_name) {
        case "latest":
        default:
            this.title = "Latest Items";
            s = this.itemService.getLatest();
            break;
        case "most-viewed":
            this.title = "Most Viewed Items";
            s = this.itemService.getMostViewed();
            break;
        case "random":
            this.title = "Random Items";
            s = this.itemService.getRandom();
            break;
    }
    s.subscribe(
        items => this.items = items,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
    //this.getLatest();
}

getLatest() {
    this.itemService.getLatest()
        .subscribe(
        latestItems => this.items = latestItems,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
}

onSelect(item: Item) {
    this.selectedItem = item;
    console.log("item with Id " + this.selectedItem.Id + " has been selected.");
}
}
```

I created another simple component Called DemoInput :

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: "demo-input",
template: `<h1>{{title_name}}</h1>`
})
export class DemoInput
{
@Input("in_name") title_name: string;
}
```

Here also the same error saying that in_name isn't a known property of demo-input.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'opengamelist',
template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>
           <item-list class_name="latest" class="latest"></item-list>
           <!--<item-list class_name="most-viewed" class="most-viewed">            </item-list>-->
           <!--<item-list class_name="random" class="random"></item-list>-->
           <!--<demo-input [in_name]="title"></demo-input>-->`,
styles: [`
        item-list {
            min-width: 332px;
            border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 10px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        item-list.latest {
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
        }
        item-list.most-viewed {
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
        }
        item-list.random {
            background-color: #e9e9e9;
        }
    `]
})
export class AppComponent {
title:string = "Open Game List"
}
```

app.module.ts

```
///<reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts"/>
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import "rxjs/Rx";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ItemListComponent } from './item-list.component';
import { ItemService } from './item.service';
import { ItemDetailComponent } from './item-detail.component';
import { DemoInput } from './DemoInput';

@NgModule({
declarations: [AppComponent, ItemListComponent, ItemDetailComponent,     DemoInput],
imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule, RouterModule],
providers: [ItemService],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule 
{

}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 on Virtual Machine Running on Mac. I tried creating the same DemoInput component on a Mac by installing Angular 2. It works fine in my Mac.

Is this a problem of Visual Studio 2015. What wrong am I doing. If I remove the item-detail tag from ItemListComponent template everything works fine.

Can anybody give me a solution.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: did you try this `@Input() item: Item;` ?

Comment: Yes I tried. Still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the exact same Angular2 version/build specified in the book? If not, please tell me what you've been using: I'm not getting this error with the RC5.

I also suggest to try to get the book source code from the official GitHub repository:

https://github.com/PacktPublishing/ASPdotNET-Core-and-Angular-2

Each chapter/book section has its own solution file: yours is *Chapter 3 - Part 1*.

As a side note: considering that `ItemDetailComponent` implementation is replaced later in Chapter 3 (*Chapter 3 - Part 2*): if you don't figure out a suitable fix for your issue you could probably just skip that sample implementation and go straight to the updated `ItemDetailComponent`.

Comment: Yes I am using the same Angular2 Version as specified in the book. I have downloaded the source code and cross verified. My code is same as in the source code. I will delete the solution and recreate it from scratch and let you know If I am able to clear the error. Thanks for the reply. Will get back to you soon.

Comment: Hi. I recreated the solution and tried again. It's working now. The only change I had made was the typescript version. Instead of ^1.8.10 I had given ^2.0.0. Could you explain me what's the difference. I just tried to use the recent version of typescript.

Comment: Hello Abhilash, I'm also using TypeScript 2 now for the book project and I have no issues, but I was forced to skip the initial builds (2.0.x) and go with 2.1.x and above ones (2.1.4.0 dev14 for example is working fine). Unfortunately TS is not always backwards-compatible, so whenever you change TypeScript version you could occasionally hit some code issues. Please read here for further info regarding how different TS versions impact the book project: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/ASPdotNET-Core-and-Angular-2/issues/1#issuecomment-268999327

Comment: Hi Darkseal. Thank you very much for the information.

Comment: I am gonna stick with 1.8.10 until I finish the book. Later will definitely play with new TS versions. :)